# Returning results from a tag-based search engine

Tags: sql, search

So i am building a search application. My application associates mulitiple terms/tags with a document. For example,

```
Doc 1
- School
- Books
- Teachers
- ...

Doc 2
- Obama
- Terror
- Election
- ...

Doc 1000
- Google
- Facebook
- Books
- ...
```

I currently use MySQL as the database. The document table has about 100,000 rows.

So my questions:

Supposing a user enters a query "School Books" which is then translated into two tags (school, books)

- How do i get all documents with this tags
- Documents having the two tags associated with them should rank higher than those with just one tag. Is there a way to carry out this ranking with just an SQL statement/query
- Is it cumplusory that all possible results be returned to the user? can i just place a limit (say 10,000)

Thanks.

EDIT

The database consist of 3 tables.

1. Tags - For the tags
2. Document - The documents
3. Document_Tags - Documents are associated with tags

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe your data model, so I'll assume you a table with at least `(document, tag)`.

You can then do...

```
SELECT
  document,
  COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  Tag IN ('school', 'books')
GROUP BY
  document
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
LIMIT
  10000
```